# Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.using storedprocedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm getting following error:

> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match
>   table definition.

Total column in excel is = 17
Total field in table = 17 + 3 = 20
among 3 fiedls 1 is (primarykeyid-autogenerate) 2 is (will get from another textbox) and 3 is (defaulvalue 1)

i don't know how to pass text box value and default value to procedure.

Please suggest me a way

Here is my stored procedure code

```
USE [Demo]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spx_ImportFromExcel07]    Script Date: 03/21/2014 18:25:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_ImportFromExcel07]
   @SheetName varchar(20),
   @FilePath varchar(300),
   @HDR varchar(3),
   @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
    IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL

      SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE'

    ELSE

      SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @TableName + ' FROM OPENDATASOURCE'


    SET @SQL = @SQL + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @HDR + ''''''')...['
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SheetName + ']'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

and here is my insertion code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FileName = lblFileName.Text;
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
            string FolderPath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"]);
            string CommandText = "";
            switch (Extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    CommandText = "spx_ImportFromExcel03";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                    CommandText = "spx_ImportFromExcel07";
                    break;
            }
            //insertDB();
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CARGONETConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SheetName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSheets.SelectedItem.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FolderPath + FileName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@HDR", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbHDR.SelectedItem.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "TB_TransAgentSeaFreightRate";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                object count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblMessage.Text = count.ToString() + " records inserted.";
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;

            }

            finally
            {

                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                Panel1.Visible = true;
                //Panel2.Visible = false;
                dg_AgentSFR.Visible = true;
            }

        }
```

Please Help me..

I dont know how to pass textbox value and defaulvalue to storedprocedure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is add additional parameters to your stored procedure and then pass those values in your `btnSave_Click()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you get rid of the dynamic SQL in your stored procedure.  Dynamic SQL will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection.  "lblFileName.Text" is the most likely place that I see in the provided code for the injection to occur, but with the way the stored procedure is written, you are vulnerable with every parameter.  You should parse the values to the correct types before you call the stored procedure.  The parameters in the stored procedure should be the type of the columns in the table respectively.  As for the table selection you are making, ask yourself how often this will change?

If it is not practical to write inserts for each table due to a large number of tables, then you need to check the stored procedure's parameters for SQL injection.

If you need a default value, you can easily put it on the stored procedure.  Then you can do a check and skip the parameter in the code behind.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spExample
   @nExample int = 1
AS
```

Code Behind:

```
int value
if(int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out value))
{
  // add parameter here.
}
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection